# SQL CASE statement error on line 11

Tags: sql

I have tried everything to correct the CASE statement but it continues to 
  error.
  I need to join three tables which are student_demo, course, and student_enroll.

Here is the query:

```
`SELECT
  sd.other_name,
  sd.first_name,
  sd.last_name,
  sd.email_address,
  sd.citizenship_code,
  sd.title,
  sd.passport_no,
  sd.alt_student_id,
  sd.district_id,
  se.school_id 

  CASE WHEN sd.other_name is null THEN 'Federated ID'
  WHEN sd.title is null THEN 'conestagevalley.org' 
  WHEN sd.passport_no is null THEN 'Default Spark with Premium Features for K-12 - 2 GB configuration' 
  WHEN sd.alt_student_id is null THEN 'Tech Students Creative Cloud Licensed' 
  WHEN sd.citizenship_code = 'US' THEN 'US'
  ELSE 'not US' END AS citizenship_code
  FROM
  student demo sd
  INNER JOIN school_id se ON se.district_id = 'CVSD'
  WHERE

  cr.department_code = 'TECED'`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to put from before case

Comment: Missing comma before CASE. (BTW, case expression, not statement.)

Comment: which db are you using? Is it mysql, sql server etc? Execute the script and post the error message. It should tell you the exact line of the error

Comment: it is for Report Writer which is a Jasper report writer.  In order to create reports we have to write a SQL queries.

Comment: If I put the comma before case I get this error:com.jaspersoft.commons.semantic.metaapi.MetaDataException: Cannot execute JDBC Query.
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: If I remove the comma I am back to this error: com.jaspersoft.commons.semantic.metaapi.MetaDataException: Cannot execute JDBC Query.
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: Does anyone know why I would be receiving the above errors?